# UPDATE with select query adding NULL rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fill in fields in a table with date of another table.

In the table 'blanko' I have a column 'product_sku' and 'virtuemart_product_id'.

In the table 'jml_virtuemart_products' I have (among others) the columns 'product_sku' and 'virtuemart_product_id'.

Now I want to add values from jml_virtuemart_products.virtuemart_product_id column into the the same column in 'blanko' from rows with where product_sku is the same.

I am trying with this query and it works partialy.

UPDATE blanko b1 SET virtuemart_product_id = (SELECT virtuemart_product_id FROM jml_virtuemart_products v1 WHEREe v1.product_sku = b1.product_sku);

The problem is that it add endless amount of rows with NULL values.
Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? I am running in circles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way is to use `join` to update the record

```
update blanko b1
join jml_virtuemart_products v1 on v1.product_sku = b1.product_sku
set b1.virtuemart_product_id = v1.virtuemart_product_id
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you.
I was surprised that an UPDATE can add records. In the light of that, is left join even better?

Comment: well INNER JOIN ensures that only update happens to the matching record instead of doing it for all columns.